# Top Right Round Corner Issues

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I cant seem to get the last right hand corners on the slideshow to round.
http://www.petrowestcorp.com/home/

```
.squarespace-slideshow-wrapper {
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px!important;  
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px!important;
border-top-right-radius: 5px!important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like it needs to be added to the `sf` selector

```
.squarespace-slideshow-animated-frame.type-fade .sf
{
    border-top-right-radius:5px
    along with webkit and -moz obviously
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your divs `header-slideshow` and `.squarespace-slideshow-wrapper` are both 980px wide but your page is only 960px thus you don't see the round corner up right.

Set width to 960px on both divs and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a new `<div>` that wraps your `pageHeaderWrapper` and `pageBodyWrapper` and then put a `border-radius` on that div instead of specifying `border-radius` for 2 different divs, and specifying which corners should have `border-radius`.

Like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="pageHeaderWrapper">
  </div>
  <div id="pageBodyWrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

This will result in a cleaner structure and less lines of code.

**Tip:** Try to steer clear of using `!important` as much as you can.